# How to have web page include all js files in a directory tree?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a JavaScript development project that will allow me to factor my code into several files.  I plan to run this eventually on a client web browser, but first I need to set up an efficient development environment.

I've used other programming languages before that let you keep a large number of files in a subdirectory and then let you compile everything into your final deployable (or have an interpreter do something similar).  Javascript doesn't seem to allow this - I have to manually add a `<script>` tag for each js file to the head of my web page to get the browser to load it.  This can get very hard to manage once you have more than about 10 files that you need to keep track of.  It would be nice if I could write `<script src="myscripts/**/*.js">` to suck in everything, at least during development time.

I've found Grunt 'uglify' which looks like it would be a handy tool for creating a final file for deployment, but during development I need to keep everything separate so I can debug properly.  Is there any way to have my web page load every js file in my development directory?

Comment: you're looking for webpack https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: as ^^ said, use webpack.js if you want to manually configure the way you want your javascript files to compile. or use a framework such as [angular](https://angular.io/) or [react](https://reactjs.org/) which has the boiler plate setup for you and a neat command line for your ease.

Comment: The above are good suggestions.  I've also discovered that JavaScript version 6 has the /import/ and /export/ key words that let you explicitly declare modules and then import them from other js files.  You only need to include the root file in your webpage if you set up your imports correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in comments, Webpack (or similar) is the way to go.  It bundles up all of your relevant code, and can also process it for minification.

I want to address this comment though:

> but during development I need to keep everything separate so I can debug properly

You don't need, or want, that.  While developing, you want to be testing against the same sort of build process you'll use in a deployment later.  So, how can you easily debug your compiled scripts?  There's a `.map` file that gets built, which tells the browser what your original code looked like.

Chrome and other browsers will automatically load and parse this file when you open your developer tools.  Then, you'll be able to see the original source code (and in the original language, for anything transpiled) and debug it as if it were not bundled in the first place.

Don't deploy this map file, unless you want external users to be able to see all your original source code.

Comment: You shouldn't try to debug minified code... It shouldn't be minified until the code is reliable and free from errors. Work forwards, not backwards.

Comment: @Matth3w Sure, have fun figuring out anything in your totally-different-environment where you're loading 80 JS files and what not.  I'd rather test my stuff in context.  Remember, if you're using a source map, the fact that your code is all compiled and minified into one module is a non-issue.

Comment: My "totally different environment" is notepad because I actually know how to code. I don't have "environment issues" to "have fun" with.